# Итерации кодировки utf8 и â символы в тексте. Как определить исходную и перекодировать?

Tags: php, utf-8, кодировка, iconv

Есть текст UTF-8 , в нем есть ряд символов вида

```
$bad_symbols = array('â', 'â','â','â');
```

[image: сюда символы не получается вставить, вот на скрине]

"В жизни" на сайте эти символы выглядят как одинарные или двойные кавычки, тире.

Это популярная тема, гуглил и нашел ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477452/%C3%A2%E2%82%AC-showing-on-page-instead-of , но я не понимаю как участники с помощью таблиц вроде этой определяют исходную кодировку https://www.charset.org/utf-8 (какова механика действий?)

Я попробовал перекодировать эти символы, получил их в виде (что за вид, кстати?)

`&#226;` = â

`&#226;&#128;&#153;` = â€™

, но что мне делать с этим дальше? Как понять исходную кодировку? И как избавиться от этого, привести к нормальному виду? Если же не получается к нормальному виду привести, то хотя-бы как определить все строки с такими символами, может есть хук какой-то? Я сейчас решаю это вручную, нахожу все такие символы и str_replace - адовый костыль.

Также пробовал все возможные варианты ICONV

```
$z = 'Itâs a pity to cut beautiful curly hair. If itâs';
iconv('CP-1252','UTF-8',$z);
iconv('windows-1252','UTF-8',$z);
iconv('ISO-8859-1','UTF-8',$z);
iconv('UTF-8','ISO-8859-1',$z);
iconv('UTF-8','CP-1252',$z);
iconv('UTF-8','windows-1252',$z);
```

Результат всегда False , и ничего не меняется!

Comment: Смотрите в сторону источника данных с этими символами... Кодировки на небольшом наборе символов отличить никак не возможно! Алгоритмы определения кодировки обычно исходят из того что некоторые символы в текстах встречаются чаще другие реже. UTF-8 это кодировка с динамической шириной символа т.е.1 символ может быть представлен как 1 так и 5 байтами остальные кодировки представленные вами однобайтные.

Comment: Конвертация через iconv вам никак не поможет, потому как с конвертацией этого символ у вас конвертнутся и другие символы в строке

Comment: @fens "Смотрите в сторону источника данных с этими символами... " - а что я могу там рассмотреть? Там написано - utf-8 , и все.

Comment: где там? Если вы про БД, то она не является в конкретном контексте источником данных. Источником кривых данных для вас является то место откуда в БД приехали эти символы.